# Calculate determinant of B, given A

Tags: linear-algebra

**QUESTION**:

Given that |BA - B| = 60. Find |B|

Let A = $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 3 & -4 \\
    0 & 3 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & -2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

**MY ANSWER:**

So far I understand that in simplified terms this means:

|B||A| - |B| = 60

I found that |A| = -18, however I just don't know how to continue from here on.

**Any** advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should have had considered
$$|BA - B| = |BA - BI| = |B||A - I|$$
Moreover, since $A - I$ is an upper triangular matrix, its determinant is given by the product of its diagonal elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|BA-B|=|B||A-I|=60$$

$$=\begin{vmatrix}2&3&-4\\0&2&-1\\0&0&-3\end{vmatrix}|B|=-12|B|=60$$

$$\implies |B|=-5$$

Comment: Can you please explain how it goes from |BA - B| to  |B||A-I|

Comment: @MathNoob First we have,

$$|BA-B|=|B(A-I)|$$

Then apply [Product rule of det](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product), we get 

$$|B(A-I)|=|B||A-I|$$

Comment: Ahh makes sense, thank you for taking the time to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

In general,
$$|BA-B|\neq |B||A|-|B|$$
This is because the determinant, while multiplicative, is not additive. The best you can do is
$$|BA-B|=|B||A-I|$$
Now $A-I$ is upper triangular, so its determinant is easy to compute (just the product of the diagonal entries).